# Why can't I loop through this dictionary?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, dictionary

I thought it would have been relatively straightforward, I am here first runing this code that uses a 3rd party software to return a set of values as a dictionary:

```
List<Dictionary<string, long>> result = 3rdPartyConnection.GetPlans(id, params);
```

I then try to loop these results (so I can populate a viewmodel with them and other values) using the following code, first I declare a new list using the viewmodel, then I loop through the results to populate the model:

```
        List<OptionViewModel> AvailableOptions = new List<OptionViewModel>();

        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, long> item in result)
        {
            OptionViewModel c = new OptionViewModel();
            c.Code = item.Key;
            c.Value = item.Value;
            AvailableOptions.Add(c);
        }
```

But it only generates the following error:

```
Error   257 Cannot convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string,long>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<string,long>'
```

I don't understand what the problem is, from what I've read on c# this is how you loop through a dictionary. I have a feeling this is a simple oversight of some kind on my part....

Comment: its a list of dictionaries - so you have to go thru the list first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to iterate through the `List` first, going through each dictionary, at which point you can then iterate through the key-value pairs:

```
foreach (Dictionary<string, long> dic in result)
{
    foreach(KeyValuePair<string, long> item in dic)
    {
        OptionViewModel c = new OptionViewModel();
        c.Code = item.Key;
        c.Value = item.Value;
        AvailableOptions.Add(c);
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 4):

It is a `List<>` of dictionaries, not a single `Dictionary<,>`. Use two `foreach` loops inside each other.

Sometimes it is better to use `var` in `foreach` loops: `foreach (var item in ...)` It helps you figure out what the iteration variable type is, without introducing a cast.

Comment: Thanks! As simple as I figured it was!